# unsupported filetype when running git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, atlassian-fisheye

I have a git repo which I'm trying to index in Fisheye/Crucible. The problem is it's failing on a specific change and throwing an unsupported filetype on a file extn ".Pdf". There is only one file with this extension causing the problem and the other with .PDF or .pdf work fine. The command being called is `git.exe diff -M --no-abbrev --full-index -U0 721dd161c288bd43b15874c03a8bfc4ae0f6aa32..af0a23599eef5612236d00ccf9cb913277171f28`

The is reproducible outside of Fisheye which points to something between git and the file??

I've tried different versions of Git (msysgit-1.9.0, 1.9.2, 1.9.4) and all exhibit the same issue. I have also added the extn to the .gitattributes file (`*.Pdf   diff=astextplain`) also without success.

When running gitk  I get the following:

```
STTopStockturnbyValue.Pdf
%PDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog 
/Pages 3 0 R 
/ViewerPreferences << 
>>
>> 
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Type /Page 
/Parent 4 0 R 
/MediaBox [0 0 596 842] 
/Resources 9 0 R
/Annots 10 0 R
/Contents 6 0 R >> 
endobj
10 0 obj
[ 
] 
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Font << /F0 11 0 R /F1 12 0 R >>
/ProcSet 8 0 R
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Length 7 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >> 
stream
xÚYYs¹~W•þžRÒ9Â}¸*cj$q5<23´­dó •i—‰ôÒò¦üïóa’\í>ˆEènt÷×øÛé   K(¥dÿsó«.‘Î)b„Me’(¥ñ…Zb¹ßÑd³<=y{zò|V§'´¦Üÿô\.®ÀS’êjRå§'Â´|O(©>žžüë¬Z%Š”Ïë‡ÿ’êûfEæËÍ§õæé~õ°üF~ýAÞÝ?~_žÿ»úùô$«
```

Not sure what to do next other than re-write the history but this will have ramifications as this is working repo used by the team.

Any suggestions?